# Using Python to get unblocked area

Tags: python, computer-vision, geometry, vision

I have a rather complicated problem. Suppose I have the shape below. You can think of the red dot as a person and the pointy shape inside the big polygon as an obstacle. My goal is to compute the total unblocked vision of the person inside the big polygon, which is the area of the polygon minus the red shaded area.

I want to write a function that takes in the coordinates of the person, the coordinates of the ordered vertices of the obstacle(s) and those of the ordered vertices of the big polygon, and returns the area of the unblocked vision.

I have tried multiple things, and I'm aware of the shoelace algorithm, but the only way that I can come up with is through monte carlo. Can I get a hint on a more intelligent and efficient way to compute the area in a closed-form way?

[image]

Comment: For the area part, triangulation once you have the vertices. But as for obtaining the vertices... Do you have access to a computational geometry book?

Comment: @mrblewog Yes. Could you give me a few keywords?

Comment: See prevoius comment: polygon triangulation, ray tracing, line of sight, ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is solved by finding the "Visibility polygon".
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visibility_polygon

You can use https://karlobermeyer.github.io/VisiLibity1/ library to compute the visibility area.

Answer (score 2):

The first task is to get the two extreme lines of sight from the person.

A simple brute-force checking. I doubt there's a better method, unless you need this calculation at each frame. (See (a) below).

Calculate the angle (relative to X-axis, or whatever) of the line person-to-obstacle_vertex for every vertex.

Find the lowest and highest values. This can be tricky if the obstacle may somehow warp around the person.

So yo can calculate the angle of each pair of sight lines (combinatory issue), an get that with maximum angle. For this job use the Dot-Product.

The second task is to get the area of the shaded region.

You need to get the two intersections of the sight lines and the outer polygon. And then build a list of vertices of the polygon between the two intersections. Add these intersections to that list.

The area can be calculated as the sum of area of triangles, those from the person to each edge (two points in that list). While you have all coordinates, an easier way is to use the Shoelace Algorithm.

(a) If the obstacle has thousands of vertices and the person moves continuosly I'd try to reduce the number of pairs to check. You can mantain a list of shown/hidden vertices, and when the person moves check the last two used vertices and their neighbours, until you get a new couple of ending vertices.